# php use fputcsv instead of INTO OUTFILE to save file

Tags: php, mysql, into-outfile

Ok, so my hosting said they do not offer the FILE privilege on shared servers, so i can't use the `INTO OUTFILE` command, my goal is to use fputcsv to save certain ROWS of my DB into a TXT and later on use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import this DATA to another DB, in order for this to work i need to save the TXT file the same exact way the `INTO OUTFILE` does, i came up with this script that does that but i was wondering if someone could take a look to see if the script could do better.

Also how can i use one `$row` to array all info, instead of `$push = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);`.

Also if there are empty ROWS to insert `\N` instead of nothing.

```
function fputcsv2 ($fp, $array, $deliminator="\",\"") {
$line = "";
foreach($array as $val)
{
$val = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $val);
if(ereg("[$deliminator\"\n\r]", $val))
{
$val = '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $val).'"';
}
$line .= $val.$deliminator;
}
$line = substr($line, 0, (strlen($deliminator) * -1));
$line .= "\"";
return fputs($fp, $line);
}

$fp=fopen("test.txt","w"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r0, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
        $push = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
        fputcsv2($fp,$push);
    }



fclose($fp)
```

Comment: why aren't you using the native [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)? It will automatically deal with delimiters in your data for you.

Comment: i know that but it wont add the separators correctly `,"`.

Comment: The mysql_ functions have been deprecated. You should look into using PDO or MySQLi.